# Custom user T4 template files location

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, entity-framework-4, t4

While developing an application using Entity Framework 4 I've faced a necessity to modify the SSDLToSQL10.tt T4 template.

All [sources](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/02/08/entity-designer-database-generation-power-pack.aspx) are pointing to %localappdata%\microsoft\[VSAppId]\10.0\extensions\microsoft\entity framework tools\dbgen folder as a proper location for customized user templates.
However this path  does not exist at my box: *extensions* folder is missing in %localappdata%\microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0

Am I missing something here?

Setup is Win7, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate RTM, no VS Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out, the location for user templates in my case (besides the VS folder in Program Files and Project directory) was created by installing the [Database Generation Power Pack](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87/) and cloning one of standard templates with it.